# RxSwift binding data to UIButton memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, rx-swift

I'm running instruments to check for memory leaks and I'm seeing a memory leak when binding this observable with the UIButton title. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix this issue?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
...
viewModel?.menuData.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: setupTopMenu).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
...
}

func setupTopMenu(items: [MenuItemViewModel]) {
        topMenuStackView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
        for (i, item) in items.enumerated() {
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            item.titleUppercased.bindTo(button.rx.title(for: .normal)).addDisposableTo(disposeBag) // memory leak 

            topMenuStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
}
```

[Instruments screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGSiM.png)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to write your subscription code like so

```
viewModel?.menuData.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in   
  self.setupTopMenu($0)
}).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

This is because when using the function passing syntax, `self` is implicitly retained. There's unfortunately no way around this.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If the closure is not owned by the class I don't think you have to use [weak/unowned self]

Comment: But in this particular example, it looks like `setupTopMenu` is a member of the view controller.